# Plotly javascript. 'plotly_click' gets on is not a function

Tags: javascript, click, plotly

I am attempting to create an onclick event on my plotly chart. Following the documentation i have created the following chart:

```
var graphDiv = document.getElementById('uniqueId');
Plotly.newPlot('uniqueId', charData, layout);
graphDiv.on('plotly_click', function (data) {
    var i = 0;
})
```

However when i run this i get the following error:

```
graphDiv.on is not a function
```

So can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Note i have also attempted with jquery:

```
$('#uniqueId').on('plotly_click', function(){})
```

This didnt throw an error but the function was not called when clicking the chart.

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/c1kt3r82/127/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fiddle you are using `plotly-basic.js`, you would need to use `plotly-latest.min.js` to get the `on` functionality.

```js
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], { 
    margin: { t: 0 } } );
    
    TESTER.on('plotly_click', function(data){
     alert('did you just click on me?!')
    })

/* Current Plotly.js version */
console.log( Plotly.BUILD );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```